# Redirect all output of a bash script, including commands

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm learning to write bash scripts and I have a script that goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
log_file="user_data.log"
exec > $log_file 2>&1

# Update list of available packages
sudo apt update

# Install required packages
sudo apt install docker.io docker-compose git nginx certbot python3-certbot-nginx -y
```

I get stdin and stderr redirected to user_data.log, however i would like to see commands (e.g. sudo apt update) in the same logfile. How do I do this?
Is there a better way to achieving this (without `sh script.sh > somewhere`)?
thank you so much for your help.

Comment: soooo `set -x`?

Comment: Answers should never be edited into questions: We want all answers to be on an even keel for voting purposes; the way to mark your question as solved and a particular answer as the one that helped you most is to click the checkbox next to it

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @KamilCuk, I needed to add this at the start of the script:

```
set -x
```